# Embed a Non-YouTube video in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, embedding

## How can I embed a video from cnbc.com or foxnews.com in a PowerPoint 2013 presentation?

I am aware of how to embed a YouTube video in PowerPoint 2013, but when I try to embed a video from any other site, like cnbc.com, I get an error.

`PowerPoint can't insert a video from this embed code. Try a different embed code or use a different website.`

**Am I just out of luck? Is my only option to download the video?**

So far I've tried using the embed code from the website and modifying the embed code source from a YouTube embedded video.

Comment: another option is to upload it to youyube yourself

Comment: @barlop I did actually consider that. However, since I do not have the video it would still require me to download the video and then to upload it. Unless there is a way to upload a video to YouTube from a separate site like cnbc?? If so that may be a solution to my problem and it should be put as an answer. If I need to download the video I might as well just add it to the PowerPoint from my machine and skip the whole uploading to YouTube process.

Comment: there are a bunch of solutions for downloading videos from websites. riptiger is very powerful though not free  i'm not sure how limited any free download / trial is http://www.riptiger.com/screenshots.html     also videohelp forum might have some ideas. Worst case scenario, something like Replay Video Capture (also not free) which captures the screen and sound. for a selected region of the screen. I'd then convert it to WMV with xilisoft converter(also not free) powerpoint plays WMV fine.